# RangeError: Invalid Key Length

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to implement Aes-128-gcm but every time I try to run the code it returns "RangeError: Invalid Key Length"

```
const crypto = require('crypto'); 
const encryptionKey = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const IV =  crypto.randomBytes(16); 

const data = "who let the dogs out";


var encrypt = ((dataValue) => {
  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-gcm', encryptionKey, IV);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(dataValue, 'utf8', 'base64');
  encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
  return encrypted;
});

var decrypt = ((encrypted) => {
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-gcm', encryptionKey, IV);
  let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'utf8');
  return (decrypted + decipher.final('utf8'));
});
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: aes-128-gcm requires a 16 bytes key and not a 32 bytes key. A 32 bytes key is required for aes-256-gcm.

Comment: Also, the GCM authentication tag is not taken into account. It must be *explicitly* determined during encryption and set during decryption.

Comment: Thanks a lot that seemed to be the issue. Another note to anyone who may face this issue, It's important to set the authorization tag before calling decipher.final()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key length depends on the algorithm, for example:

- aes128 corresponds to 16 bytes
- aes192 corresponds to 24 bytes
- aes256 corresponds to 32 bytes

So you need to have a key length of 16 bytes (128 bits). You could create the key as follows:

```
const key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(String(secret)).digest('base64').slice(0, 16)
```